# Rotating a ship 360*

Tags: c#, xna

In game Im trying to make, I have some ships(not space ships or so, actual ships they are in water)

If I just directly rotate them, I get absurd results.

Do I need to make 8 picture for each ship ? (considering there is 8 direction)
Are there any way that I can do it with just creating one image or at least a few, instead of 8 ?

Comment: Are these 2d images drawn with SpriteBatch.Draw or are these 3d models?

Comment: Having 8 different images might not be a bad idea, particularly if your direcions are limited to just 8.

Comment: having 8 different image will work, but you know... it requires 8 different image :)

Comment: Whaat are these absurd results you're getting?

Comment: very stupid results. just open photoshop or something similiar and rotate a real picture :) thats pretty much what I am getting.

Comment: you are not giving us **nearly** enough detail to answer your question. First things first - is this a top down game, isometric, side scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, rotation mathematics are an interpretation of the original image.

Sure, it works depending on the complexity of the image and the relationship of straightlines and things that are perpendicular, but some things just *dont* work.

If you're doing a top-down 2D game with ships, I'm going to assume Sail ships here, then rotating mathematically really just isn't going to look good as the sails them selves will move and angle depending on Wind speed/direction and the angle of the ship.

Long story short ? Mathematical rotation works well for an Asteroids style triangle ship, doesn't work well for proper graphics.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking 2D graphics and are getting "absurd results" I'm assuming you're not taking into account an origin.  If you have a Texture2D and give it a rotation value, it will be rotating by the default origin which is (0,0).  Try setting your origin in your spritebatch.Draw call to a new Vector2(texture.width / 2, texture.height / 2) and see if that is a step in the right direction.

Another approach would be to have a spritesheet with the 8 drawings that you mention and reference a different source rectangle of the texture2D.